# What are the necessary steps that I need to do to download a website's manifest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I basically want to scrape a website and get it's manifest

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```

and inspect it. What would be the best way to approach this using Javascript/Node? Which libraries would I need, etc.

Comment: Hey! I'm going to write an answer in a minute, but just wanted to let you know that this question seems relatively broad. Most of the time, people on stackoverflow do respond better to more focussed questions, like "How could I find a value for a tag in html using node", because for example, I guess you could find out yourself how do download a file once you got the path ;)

Answer (score 0):

When scraping html on node, there are a lot of libraries that could help. The one I default to is cheerio (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio). It has an api similar to jquery, so it would be something like

```
let $ = cheerio.load(...);
let $manifest_link = $('link[rel=manifest]');
let path = $manifest_link.attr('href');

// Check whether or not path == null and do something with it
```

After that you append that path to url that you got the page from,
download it (enough libraries for that, I myself keep using node-fetch (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) because of the similar API it has to browser fetch) and voila :)